# React proxy does not work even though config is set properly

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, express

I have tried multiple things

I added

```
"proxy": "http://localhost:5000/"
```

to package.json,
and even

```
devServer: {
    historyApiFallback: true,
     proxy: {
     "/": "http://localhost:5000"
     }
  }
```

to webpack.config.dev.js

However, none of these seem to work. When I go to localhost:3000/age (one of my routes), the backend does not receive any request even though the React component is tied to it AND I have the proxy set in package.json

My express app listens on route 5000, and I am visiting it through my browser as localhost:3000/age and also have tried localhost:5000/age but don't work

Comment: Are you sure  `localhost:5000/age` available on express route.please check it directly on browser url

Comment: @prasanth I have a react router which loads a component when the path is ‘/age’, but going to that route in my browser says CANNOT GET ‘/age’. I do not have a get request, but my React Router is supposed to load a component

Comment: please set the [route on express](https://expressjs.com/en/guide/routing.html) .Because you are request on express router.react router is client router. its not performed by the express js

Comment: But if react has a proxy, then shouldn’t react router use the same route as express? I’ll try and use fetch requests in my React app to use express, instead of react router

Comment: why type of request you did `direct url` call or a `ajax request` for the url `localhost:3000/age` ?

Comment: @prasanth Direct url by typing it into chrome

Comment: for development react have own server. And Package json proxy only work on fetch and ajax [check this issue](https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/issues/1378) .it you need a react side route better [try this one](https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/guides/quick-start). After the production build its working same as you expect

Comment: could anyone look at this please - same issue but not able to resolve - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76769186/react-app-not-hitting-node-endpoint-how-to-debug-if-communication-is-working-be/76769606?noredirect=1#comment135348443_76769606

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check this [documentation](https://create-react-app.dev/docs/proxying-api-requests-in-development/)
[image]

> The development server will only attempt to send requests without text/html in its Accept header to the proxy.

If you access directly on browser. its set content type header as `text/html` .So its not working . Better use only for an ajax/fetch request .

**[issue](https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/issues/1378)**

for development react have own server.if you need a react side route better try [react-route](https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/guides/quick-start)r. After the production build its working same as you expect

Comment: could anyone look at this please - same issue but not able to resolve - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76769186/react-app-not-hitting-node-endpoint-how-to-debug-if-communication-is-working-be/76769606?noredirect=1#comment135348443_76769606

Answer (score 0):

You need to set your proxy your backend's port. 
If your backend is listening on 5000 then it should be
`"proxy": "http://localhost:5000"`

By default any http requests in react to a sites own domain use whatever port the app is running on. Since react is running on 5000 itll send all requests through that port. The proxy tells it to change this default behavior to the specified proxy.

Comment: D'oh!! I flipped the numbers around in my head while reading it!! :) there must be another deeper issue then.

Comment: could anyone look at this please - same issue but not able to resolve - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76769186/react-app-not-hitting-node-endpoint-how-to-debug-if-communication-is-working-be/76769606?noredirect=1#comment135348443_76769606