# React app not hitting node endpoint. How to debug if communication is working between the two

Tags: node.js, reactjs

The following code is suppose to hit a `node` endpoint and get a response. However, nothing in the logs, both on client or server side are showing that the request was actually sent by `React` to `node`. How could I debug it?

```
function App() {

  /*const [data, setData] = React.useState([]);

  React.useEffect(() => {
    fetch("/")
      .then((res) => {
        console.log(`got response stringified ${JSON.stringify(res)}`);
        res.json()
      }).then((data) => {
        console.log(`data : ${data}`);
        setData(data)
      });
  }, []);
  */

  useEffect( () => {
    fetchItems();
  },[]);

  const [items,setItems] = useState([]);

  const fetchItems = async () => {
    const data = await fetch('/');
    const items = await data.json();
    setItems(items);
  }


  return (
    <div className="App">
      <header className="App-header">
        <img src={logo} className="App-logo" alt="logo" />
        <p>
          {!items ? "Loading..." : items}
        </p>
      </header>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

- I have set proxy at `React` to contact `Node`. I don't know if there is a communication issue there.
- I have seen network logs on browser but I don't see request sent to `node`
- I have added console logs at server but they don't get printed when endpoint is suppose to be called
- I have tried two version but none are working

I am running out of ideas.

Comment: Can you please share how you have set the proxy? That can help in debugging.

Comment: In `package.json` of `React` folder at top level. `{
  "proxy": "http://localhost:4000",
  "name": "reactfrontend",
  "version": "0.1.0", ...`

Comment: Please try using "proxy": "h t t p : / / 1 2 7 . 0 . 0 . 1 : 4000 ", it might help.

Comment: tried `http://127.0.0.1:4000"` and `https://127.0.0.1:4000"`

Comment: Sorry, add a forward slash at the end, "h t t p : / / 1 2 7 . 0 . 0 . 1 : 4000/"

Comment: Also, try to restart the react app

Comment: There is certainly a communication issue between `react` and `node`. `node` is running at `port` `4000`, `react` on `3000`. It hasn't got a route `/hello`. When I run `localhost:4000\hello` i.e. connect with `node` directly, I get `404`. However, I get the same home page of `React` when I connect via `react` using run `localhost:3000/hello`

Comment: This documentation (https://create-react-app.dev/docs/proxying-api-requests-in-development/) says that `Any unrecognized request without a text/html accept header will be redirected to the specified proxy.` However, my request has `text/html` header. I am certain however  that there should be some other issue as I should have to change headers to make such a simple application work

Answer (score 0):

You can start by looking at what's in the data variable:

```
const data = await fetch('/');
console.log(data)
const items = await data.json();
```

and making sure that requests to the backend are handled correctly by sending an API request without using React, for example, using [postman](https://www.postman.com/) or if your are using VSCode, [you can use an extension made for that purpose](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=humao.rest-client).

Comment: the backend is working fine. Tested it by directly connecting to the endpoint. `data` is empty. However, it is probably because `React` client isn't reaching `node` at all. Is there a way to debug `fetch` to see if the call was successful?

Comment: Depending on the browser, but usually there is a network tab in in the browser's debugger [chrome example](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/devtools/network/#load)

Answer (score 0):

I am happy to receive a better answer / explanation but it seems that if the route is `/` i.e. if I `fetch('/')` the root path, it returns the index.html from the React public folder. If I use any other path, fetch('/api') for instance, proxy works and points to the Express server.

Not sure if this is expected behavior, or why If it is?

https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/issues/1378